# How to pass the value from controller to directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

Helllo,

i want to pass the one value from controller to directive in angularjs. how would i pass the value and display it in directive .

**in Html Section**

**in controller section**
my controller name is docontroller.

$scope.name = "world";

angular.element(document.querySelector('#carControls')).append($compile(
mydirectivename as tag
)($rootScope));

i have to pass my variable as well as controller in which i can get direct access in my directives 
it is my directive used in controller and appended to html
**in my directive section**

```
myApp.directive('Controls', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window) {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
alertr('name' + scope.name);      
  $timeout(function () {

            scope.controlClass = 'fa fa-pause';
            var ControlsTemplate =

                '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-r-10 text-center"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i></button>'+
                '<button ng-click="doPlayOrPause()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-r-10 text-center"><i id="play-pause" ng-class="controlClass"></i></button>'+
                '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-r-10 text-center"><i class="fa fa-forward"></i></button>'+
                '<button ng-click="doStop()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm margin-r-10 text-center"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></button>';

            element.html(ControlsTemplate);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);



        });  
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: linker
    };
});
```

in return
i passed controller :'docontroller bt i cant find my name in scope'

Comment: you can use $watch to access the scope value in directive

Comment: why are you doing it like this... getting an element and appending using $compile... you need to get over jquery ways of doing things...

Answer (score 3):

in you controller

```
$scope.yourValue="myValue";
```

in your directive

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
 return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            yourValue: '='
        },
})
```

in your dom

```
<my-directive your-value="yourValue"></my-directive>
```

checkout this  [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/oc9upd4r/)

Comment: i want to display it it in directive

Comment: this is the right way to do it, show us the non working code with this solution

Comment: angular.element(document.querySelector('#carControls')).append($compile('<controls your-value="yourValue"></controls>')($rootScope));

Comment: still it is not display in directive

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using isolated scope than you can access parent controller $scope.

you can also use $rootScope.

like

Controller :

```
app.controller("demoCtrl",function($scope,$rootScope){

   $rootScope.xyz = "test";
// call your directive , value will be accessible in directive
})
```

Directive :

```
app.directive(...,function($rootScope){
 return   {
 // extra code omitted.

  // get your value here like
  // var abc =  $rootScope.xyz;

}
)
```