# Pass controller variable value to directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a fiddle that I found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910257/how-to-pass-the-value-from-controller-to-directive-in-angular-js) answer on SO

I've modified the fiddle for my situation in the following way:

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.func = function() {
     $scope.name = "Test Name";
    } 
  })
  .directive("myDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
      template: "<div>{{name}}</div>",
      scope: {
        name: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
        alert(scope.name);
      }

    }
  });
```

Basically, I am trying to pass a variable value from a scope function to the directive - but the alert message shows up an **undefined** value.

Any idea as to what is going wrong here? How can I pass the value stored within $scope.name within the $scope.func function and pass it to the directive?

The updated fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oc9upd4r/110/).

Comment: The alert function is executing before the data is set by the controller. Do you want the alert to fire every time the value changes? Consider adding a controller and using the `$onChanges` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining name inside a function in your controller and that function is never called. Change to this.

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Test Name";
  })
  .directive("myDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
      template: "<div>{{name}}</div>",
      scope: {
        name: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
        alert(scope.name);
      }

    }
  });

<div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div my-directive name="name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could call it by keeping the function? I am making another GET call within that function to fetch the data that I'm storing to my variable that needs to be sent to the directive.

Comment: you just reassign to new value once your API returns. 2-way binding takes care of the update/re-rendering.

Comment: Add an `ng-if="name"` to your directive so that it will instantiate once you define name. `<div my-directive name="name" ng-if="name">`

Answer (score 0):

The alert function is executing before the data is set by the controller.

To see value changes, add a controller and use `$onChanges` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks):

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
      template: "<div>{{name}}</div>",
      scope: {
        ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶
        name: '<'
      },
      controller: function() {  
        this.onChanges = function(changesObj) {
           if (changesObj.name) {
             alert(changesObj.name.currentValue);
           };
        };
      }
    }
});
```

Also note that one-time `<` binding is used instead of two-way `=` binding.